# JSON Data with RxJS Observables: Filter not working

Tags: json, angular, filter, rxjs

First of all: [Plunkr Example is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5CD7s245AbVZxfnm4qzT?p=preview)  `<-- NOW: WORKING EXAMPLE (edited)`

This is the data:

```
[
  {
    "label": "One",
    "value": 1
  }, 
  {
    "label": "Two",
    "value": 2
  }, 
  {
    "label": "Three",
    "value": 3
  }
]
```

This is the filter:

```
  http.get('./data.json')
  .map(data => data.json())
  .filter ( 
    (x,index) => return x[index].value === 2
  )
  .subscribe(data => this.d = data);
```

I would like to get as result:

```
{
  "label": "Two",
  "value": 2
}
```

Maybe I've a blackout, where is the mistake?

Comment: try a console log in filter just to check if thats what you're really receiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use `.concatMap`

```
http.get('./data.json')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .concatMap(res => res)
  .filter(x => x.value === 2)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.d = data;
  });
```

[`Example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/MqH8WobgdAEtG65Ky3Hb?p=preview)